# How to fetch records in the data given through sql

Tags: sql

```
URN New_Value       Old_Value   Insert_Timestamp
1   A               B           01:00
2   C               A           02:00
3   A               D           03:00
4   B               E           04:00
5   G               B           05:00
6   I               J           06:00
```

I need to extract only URN 1 to 6. Because all other URN contains either `new_value` or `old_value` which is already used at timestamp earlier than their timestamp.

Comment: Honestly can't make sense of this question ... reformatting might help.

Comment: Still some more clarification needed. Give a little bit larger dataset (with data that you should get with the query and thus which rows you shouldn't get). Also, based on what condition exactly are you trying to get those values?

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.*
from MyTable t1
left outer join MyTable t2 on (t1.New_Value = t2.New_Value or t1.New_Value = t2.old_Value) 
    and t2.Insert_Timestamp < t1.Insert_Timestamp
left outer join MyTable t3 on (t1.Old_Value = t3.Old_Value or t1.Old_Value = t3.New_Value) 
    and t3.Insert_Timestamp < t1.Insert_Timestamp 
where t2.URN is null and t3.URN is null
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a996b/3)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `not exists` clause code:

```
select * from tab t
where not exists
(
  select * from tab t2
  where t2.Insert_Timestamp<t.Insert_Timestamp
  and (t.New_Value=t2.New_Value or t.Old_Value=t2.Old_Value or
       t.Old_Value=t2.New_Value or t.New_Value=t2.Old_Value )
)
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/874d3/1/0) DEMO

Comment: Me too, It's very useful :). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Performance will probably be very poor with this schema and requirement but

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable T1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   YourTable T2
                   WHERE  T2.Insert_Timestamp < T1.Insert_Timestamp
                          AND ( T2.New_Value IN ( T1.New_Value, T1.Old_Value )
                                 OR T2.Old_Value IN ( T1.New_Value, T1.Old_Value ) ))
```

Comment: beat me by 37 seconds with exactly the same solution

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know what database server you're using, or what your ultimate goal is, I can imagine a generic SQL statement might work. You can use something like this:

```
SELECT
 URN,
 New_Value,
 Old_Value,
 Insert_Timestamp
FROM
 table t
WHERE
 t.URN BETWEEN 1 AND 6
```